# Got 500 response for POST request to my Azure App Service-hosted website, Application Insights show System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio

I have a ASP.NET project created in Visual Studio to which I only made minor code changes (to the original template code). On localhost it works perfectly fine and respond correctly to requests I made in postman. After changing the project's database from the on-premise database to Azure SQL Database in Visual Studio

[image: screenshot]

and publishing the website with Azure App Service, I made a POST request to its `{website URL}/api/Account/Register` in Postman and received HTTP 500 response. I enabled Application Insights and saw that the error is thrown by `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.
The request content is this following JSON:

```json
{  
  "Email": "samplestring@10.com",  
  "Password": "sample string 2A",  
  "ConfirmPassword": "sample string 2A"  
}
```

Beginning of my web.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="Secrets" userSecretsId="412fec06-0301-437c-bf1c-e7294ab06ecf" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecretsConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[token]" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
  <connectionStrings>
      <!-- <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20230722024137.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20230722024137;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> -->
      <!-- <add name="haw057"
                connectionString="Server=tcp:<database>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=webapplication2_db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=haw057;Password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
                providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> -->
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I commented the `connectionStrings` part out because I'm thinking I already connected to the Azure SQL DB with Visual Studio - I didn't add anything in the code for Application Insights but connected to it with the Visual Studio UI and it works.
I tried various potential solutions, including adding all IP addresses to Azure SQL server firewall rule, making the request with VScode's REST client extension instead of Postman but none of these changed the HTTP 500 response. What should I do?
Thank you for any suggestion...I'm stuck here for a few days.

Comment: Could you please share the code.

Comment: Do not add images to your questions, refer [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) guidance. Your code is not able to establish connection to the SQL server - check the connection string is proper, you have to show the code which tries to connect. Are you connecting using username/password or managed identity of your web api app?

Comment: Is the App Service in Windows/Linux? I will try ssh tab in App Service if it is Linux and see if i can test the port connection from that App to DB. Same can be done for App Service in Windows, but not sure the name

Comment: @Harshitha Added. The template is many folders but this is the beginning of the Web.config file, everything in code that's relevant to outer connections I think. Is this sufficient? Thanks

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thanks a lot for the guide. I attempted username/password and it didn't work so I commented it out as you see above. However, I'm thinking that since I have made the connection using the Visual Studio UI there's no need to add code for this, am I right...?

Comment: @WWW It's in Windows unfortunately but thank you!

Comment: I see you are using .Net Framework. My guess here is your thought on "I commented the connectionStrings part out because I'm thinking I already connected to the Azure SQL DB with Visual Studio" is incorrect.
In your code, you should be somewhere referring the connection string with the config name DefaultConnection, which your "new" one connect to the Azure SQL DB should also have the same name, and that particular connection string from the DB should be used, unless you have set in the App Service Connection String.